# CreateFileA Parameters Explanation

Tags: windows, api

I see the parameter FILE_APPEND_DATA (in the dwDesiredAccess position) suggested when wanting to Append data to a file (in anwser to questions on the forum) but reading the MS docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea - this parameter is not listed. Anyone know if there is a documentation resource anywhere that would detail all the possible parameters for calling CreateFileA - I am trying to get to grips with it :-)

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: about `FILE_APPEND_DATA` more [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntcreatefile) - *If only the FILE_APPEND_DATA and SYNCHRONIZE flags are set, the caller can write only to the end of the file, and any offset information on writes to the file is ignored. However, the file is automatically extended as necessary for this type of write operation.* (note that `SYNCHRONIZE` access is always implicit set by CreateFile). also `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` flag is **incompatible** with the `FILE_APPEND_DATA` access. also this can not be used for directory

Comment: The `CreateFileA` documentation page you found links to [File access rights constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/file-access-rights-constants) right from the *`dwDesiredAccess`* parameter description, that's where `FILE_APPEND_DATA` is listed as a valid parameter.  But it doesn't describe the semantics fully, although you do get a brief summary: "For local files, write operations will not overwrite existing data if this flag is specified without FILE_WRITE_DATA."